# move output file after ember build is complete

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm using ember-cli 0.0.28 which depends BroccoliJS to build the distributable source for my front-end application. The problem I'm having is that whenever I (re)build I need the index.html file to be copied (or rather moved) to my back-end's template directory from which I serve the application.

I can't figure out how to configure the Brocfile.js in the ember-cli project directory to do this **after the build** is complete.

I've used a symlink for the time being, which works but would be a dead link until the front-end application is built with `ember build`. I think it's possible to use [grunt-broccoli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-broccoli) to run the build as a grunt task?! I don't know if this is the way forward though.

Using broccoli-file-mover is easy enough but it works with current trees, not future trees!

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a suitable solution for this? I'm facing a similar situation.

Comment: @jdmcnair I haven't actually, but I'm using a symlink to get around this for the time being.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29020353/227176) might have some promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/) has progressed quite a bit but this question is still, fundamentally, valid and there are myriad of ways to address it.

If the front-end build is to be bundled with the back-end assets, a symlink from the build/dist directory to the back-end's assets directory is adequate for most development phases.

Now, ember-cli also allows proxying to the back-end via the [ember server](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli) command which is useful if building an API backed app, sort of thing.

[ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/) also appears as an excellent way to deploy front-end apps which can help with deploying to a development or production environment. It has many packs but I've reverted to using the redis pack as it provides an easy way to checkout font-end revision with a small back-end tweak, like this:

```
defmodule PageController do
  def index(conn, %{"index_id" => sha}) do
    case _fetch_page_string(sha) do
      {:ok, output_string} -> html(conn, output_string)
      {:error, reason} -> conn |> send_resp(404, reason)
    end
  end

  defp _fetch_page_string(sha) do
    # some code to fetch page string (content)
    ... 
  end
end
```

In the above index page handler, attempt to catch an `index_id` queryParam, if present, we look for the corresponding page string that can be checked into e.g., a key/value store.