# How do I execute a post build hook in an ember-cli Brocfile.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have a ember-cli project that builds to the `dist/` directory. I've configured the app to handle assets in the `dist/` directory and set the history to use a hash instead of pushState. This allows me to sym-link the `index.html` to the root. The reasoning is that pushing the project to `gh-pages` on GitHub requires a root `index.html` and ember apps require routing to be absolute not relative (AFAIK). GitHub however will not follow sym-links and require a copy of the output `index.html`. This works and now I have 2 build steps (`ember build` and `cp dist/index.html ./index.html`).

How do I tell my `Brocfile.js` to copy the outputted `index.html` file after it is done building?

A bit of back-history: I am developing an ember-cli addon. I'm hosting it on GitHub. I need to provide a demo site. `gh-pages` is the correct place to host the demo site. So I create an ember-cli app in the `gh-pages` branch. I could not set the output folder to `./` because the ember build will `rm -rf` the output directory destroying the source. So it has to be `dist/`. I couldn't use a `<meta http-equiv="Refresh"...` because Ember borked up the paths and crashes on start. So the solution I had was to sym-link/copy the `index.html` to a higher level and change ember's config to prepend the `dist/` directory to assets and set the routing to hash instead of pushState.

I currently have a `deply.sh` script that does this but I wanted to know if there was a way using Broccoli for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We this for over at [Ghost](http://github.com/tryghost/ghost). Use ember-cli to generate an in-repo-addon for yourself, and then use your favorite library for copying the file (I already had fs-extra and am using it)

Create your addon with `ember g in-repo-addon <addon-name>`

in `/lib/<addon-name>/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: '<addon-name>',
    postBuild: function (results) {
        var fs = this.project.require('fs-extra');
        fs.copySync(results.directory + '/index.html', '../server/views/default.hbs');
    }
};
```

[Example from Ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/lib/asset-delivery/index.js)

Ember-cli docs: [developing addons](http://www.ember-cli.com/#developing-addons-and-blueprints) and [scaffolding in-repo addons](http://www.ember-cli.com/#detailed-list-of-blueprints-and-their-use)

Comment: Do you host your addon in a private npm repository or via guthub? Or is there a way to have an addon be included in an ember-cli app codebase?

Comment: Looked at the code linked. You include it in the app repo. I'm going to edit the answer for others who might need more explanation like I did. Thank you BTW I would have never known you can write your own add-ons inside a project! My co-workers are going to hallelujah with this news.

Comment: Hey Sukima, sorry for the late response - I don't frequent this site too often ;)
You're right that `ember generate addon` is for making external addons; the command to build an in-reop addon is `ember g in-repo-addon`
So for instance, to build my addon, I ran `ember g in-repo-addon asset-delivery` then edited the created index.js. No other work is necessary.

Comment: Oh wow, the `in-repo-addon` seemed like an undocumented feature as far as I could tell. It was buried deep in the docs. Great to know it's there! Thanks.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, so I wrote an addon to copy files out after build: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-post-build-copy